# I created a form for input elements in input added i and now in the place where i input does not work, why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

import React from 'react';

function Owner() {
return (


Owner




Name

```
            <div className="relative w-full flex justify-center items-center">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    id="name" 
                    className="peer relative w-full bg-gray-700 border-none outline-none py-4 px-2.5 rounded-md 
                    text-white font-semibold text-base transition duration-300 shadow-sm placeholder-transparent"
                    placeholder = "Subscribe status"
                /> 
                <i className=" -top-3 absolute text-xs left-0 py-3.5 px-2.5 font-semibold text-gray-200 transition-all
                duration-500 peer-placeholder-shown:text-base peer-placeholder-shown:top-0 
                peer-placeholder-shown:text-gray-500 peer-focus:-top-3 peer-focus:text-xs peer-focus:text-gray-200">
                    Subscribe status</i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

);
}

export default Owner;

I tried changing css but it didn't work

Comment: Please elaborate on "it didn't work"; what happens? Does it give an error?

Comment: It does not give an error, the changes I made in css did not help (I changed the font, display on various elements), once again, I have i located in input and in the place where i is located, it does not give me focus on input

Comment: But if I click on input elsewhere everything works

Comment: Please elaborate on *I have i located in input*; I'm not sure what this means? Your code indicates an input element, and an `<i>` element as the input's sibling, next to it.

Comment: Also, your css classes are meaningless here because you didn't include css in your question. But I don't know that they are reelvant. It seems you want clicking on the `<i>` element to focus the input? I'm not familiar with react or tailwind, but I'm assuming the `className` attribute is parallel to html's `class` attribute?

Comment: It seems you want clicking on the <i> element to focus the input? yes, I'm not familiar with react or tailwind, but I'm assuming the className attribute is parallel to html's class attribute? Yes

Comment: Wrap the `<input>` and `<i>` tags in a `<label>`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.